# Segmentation fault on return

Tags: c++, windows

I get a segmentation fault on return of this function (inside the last for), and I have no idea why (I'm going crazy, because can't make sense out of this problem).

`frase` is a global variable. The function is a copy of another function that works and I modified only the last for (I write a comment before to show you better). If the function returns at line `{cout<<"404 "<<endl;return 404;}` I get no error. I hope I have explained everything that's necessary.

```
int funzione_principale()
{
    //string frase;
    char frase_char [1024]={'\0'};
    char frase_elaborata [1024]={'\0'};

    PlaySound(TEXT("Avviso.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    rec(); //REGISTRO L' AUDIO
    while(active)
        Sleep(50); // HERE I WAIT OTHER FUNCTION TO COMPLETE!
    if(frase.length()<=14)
    {
        cout<<"404 "<<endl;return 404;
    }
    frase.copy(frase_char,frase.length()-57,56);
    for(int k=0; frase_char[k]!='"';k++)
    {
        frase_elaborata[k]=frase_char[k];
    }
    //tramite fparole otteniamo il numero di parole contenute nella frase_elaborata
    righe=fparole(frase_elaborata);
    //MANIPOLAZIONE DELLE PAROLE NELAL FRASE TRAMITE MATRICE
    char matrice [righe][27];
    for(int x=0;x<=righe;x++)
        memset(matrice[x],0,27);
    int conto=0;
    int indice=0;
    int riga=0;
    int lunghezza=strlen(frase_elaborata);
    minuscole_accenti(frase_elaborata);
    cout<<"Frase tradotta: "<<frase_elaborata<<endl;
    while (frase_elaborata[conto]!='\0')
    {
        if(frase_elaborata[conto]>=97 && frase_elaborata[conto]<=122)
        {
            matrice[riga][indice]=frase_elaborata[conto];
            indice++;
        }
        if(frase_elaborata[conto]>=48 && frase_elaborata[conto]<=57)
        {
            matrice[riga][indice]=frase_elaborata[conto];
            indice++;
        }
        if(frase_elaborata[conto]==' ' && conto!=lunghezza-1 && frase_elaborata[conto+1]!=' ')
        {
            matrice[riga][indice]='\0';
            indice=0;
            riga++;
        }
        conto++;
    }
    //ADESSO LA MATRICE CONTIENE NUM RIGHE CON OGNIUNA, UNA PAROLA DELLA FRASE
    cout<<"Frase presente nella matrice: "<<endl;
    for(int x=0;x<=righe;x++)
        cout<<matrice[x]<<endl;

    // FROM HERE I MODIFIED THE FUNCTION !

    for(int t=0;t<=righe;t++)
    {
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"s")==0)
        {return 1;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"si")==0)
        {return 1;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"affermativo")==0)
        {return 1;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"ok")==0)
        {return 1;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"certo")==0)
        {return 1;}

        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"no")==0)
        {return -1;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"negativo")==0)
        {return -1;}

        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"dopo")==0)
        {return 0;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"rimanda")==0)
        {return 0;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"rimandalo")==0)
        {return 0;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"non")==0 && strcmp(matrice[t+1],"ora")==0)
        {return 0;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"chiedi")==0 && strcmp(matrice[t+1],"dopo")==0)
        {return 0;}
        if(strcmp(matrice[t],"chiedimelo")==0 && strcmp(matrice[t+1],"dopo")==0)
        {return 0;}

    }
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: is `matrice[t+1]` correct in the last for loop? Looks like accessing the array out of bounds... (haven't read all code)

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You right, i will fix, thanks! ( but, it's not a big problem, because i'm sure that if strcmp about matrice[t] and "non" (and the other) return 0, this means that matrice[t+1] is accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in 2 places (same problem). Your `for` loop runs from 0 to `righe` INCLUSIVE, and you do that twice. One time you write to illegal memory space (`for(int x=0;x<=righe;x++) memset(matrice[x],0,27);`), and the 2nd time you read it. The for should be `for(int x=0;x<righe;x++)`.

Comment: You right!, but if righe=0, this make the function not works for me, so i change only the line 'char matrice [righe+1][27];' and works! Thank you :D